Largest possible relative error
Output
\$20\$ float64s with absolute value between 1 and 2 inclusive whose sum has the largest possible relative error. We can assume the true sum is not zero.
The sum is to be computed from left to right in a loop in the obvious fashion.
The relative error is abs(true sum - computed sum)/true sum.
Score
The relative error you achieve. Larger is better.
This is different Find 10 float64s that give the least accurate sum which asks about absolute error. Good answers to that question will not be good answers to this question.

63x
#include <stdio.h>
#include <initializer_list>


static double aim = 0;
const double eps = 2.220446049250313e-16;
// 1.0000000000000000 1.9999999999999998 1.9999999999999996 1.9999999999999996 1.9999999999999993 -1.0000000000000004 -1.9999999999999993 -1.9999999999999996 -1.9999999999999993 -1.9999999999999993 => 14.0000000000000000

void f() {double a6=0,a7=0,a8=0,a9=0,a10=0,b6=0,b7=0,b8=0,b9=0,b10=0;
    double a1 = 1;
    for (double a2: {2., 2-eps})
    for (double a3: {a2, a2-eps})
    for (double a4: {a3, a3-eps})
    for (double a5: {a4, a4-eps})
    for (double a6: {a5, a5-eps})
    for (double a7: {a6, a6-eps})
    for (double a8: {a7, a7-eps})
    for (double a9: {a8, a8-eps})
    for (double a10: {a9, a9-eps})
    for (double b1=-1; b1>-1-100*eps; b1-=eps)
    for (double x=-2; x<-2+100*eps; x+=eps)
    for (double b2: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b3: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b4: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b5: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b6: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b7: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b8: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b9: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps})
    for (double b10: {x, x+eps, x+2*eps}) {{
        long double m = (long double) a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + b7 + b8 + b9 + b10;
        if (m == 0) goto r;
        double q = (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + b7 + b8 + b9 + b10 - m)/m;
        if (q<0) q=-q;
        if (q>aim) {
            printf("%.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f %.16f => %.16f\n", a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, aim=q); } 
            }r:;
    }
}

int main() {
    f();
    }


1.0000000000000000 1.9999999999999998 1.9999999999999996 1.9999999999999996 1.9999999999999993 1.9999999999999991 1.9999999999999991 1.9999999999999991 1.9999999999999989 1.9999999999999987 -1.0000000000000160 -1.9999999999999973 -1.9999999999999973 -1.9999999999999973 -1.9999999999999973 -1.9999999999999973 -1.9999999999999976 -1.9999999999999978 -1.9999999999999976 -1.9999999999999978 => 63.0000000000000000


Rust, Relative error 66.0
#![feature(float_next_up_down)]
fn main() {
    let e = 2.0f64.powi(-52);
    let x1 = 1.0f64;
    let x2 = 2.0f64 - e;
    let x3 = 2.0f64 - e * 2.0;
    let x4 = 2.0f64 - e * 4.0;
    let x5 = 2.0f64 - e * 8.0;
    let y1 = -1.875f64 - e * 8.0;
    let y2 = -1.875f64 - e * 4.0;
    let y3 = -1.875f64 - e * 2.0;
    let y4 = -1.875f64 - e * 1.0;
    let y5 = -2.0f64;
    let y6 = -2.0f64 + e * 65.0;
    let v = vec![
        x1, x2, x3, x3, x4, x4, x4, x4, x5, x5,
        y1, y2, y2, y2, y2, y3, y3, y4, y5, y6
    ];
    let errors = vec![
        x1 - 1.0, x2 - 2.0, x3 - 2.0, x3 - 2.0, x4 - 2.0,
        x4 - 2.0, x4 - 2.0, x4 - 2.0, x5 - 2.0, x5 - 2.0,
        y1 + 1.875, y2 + 1.875, y2 + 1.875, y2 + 1.875, y2 + 1.875,
        y3 + 1.875, y3 + 1.875, y4 + 1.875, y5 + 2.0, y6 + 2.0
    ];
    let mut sum = 0.0;
    let mut true_sum = 0.0;
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        sum += v[i];
        true_sum += errors[i];
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
    println!("True: {:.60}", true_sum);
    println!("Got:   {:.60}", sum);
    println!("Rel.Error: {:.10}", (sum - true_sum).abs() / true_sum.abs());
}

Output:
[1.0, 1.9999999999999998, 1.9999999999999996, 1.9999999999999996,
 1.9999999999999991, 1.9999999999999991, 1.9999999999999991,
 1.9999999999999991, 1.9999999999999982, 1.9999999999999982,
 -1.8750000000000018, -1.8750000000000009, -1.8750000000000009,
 -1.8750000000000009, -1.8750000000000009, -1.8750000000000004,
 -1.8750000000000004, -1.8750000000000002, -2.0, -1.9999999999999856]
True: -0.000000000000000222044604925031308084726333618164062500000000
Got:   0.000000000000014432899320127035025507211685180664062500000000
Rel.Error: 66.0000000000

Try it on Rust Playground!
Got a hint from l4m2's solution that I can keep increasing the error while coming back to e.

Rust, Relative error 37.0
#![feature(float_next_up_down)]
fn main() {
    let x1 = 2.0f64;
    let x2 = x1.next_down(); // -1e
    let x3 = x2.next_down(); // -2e
    let x4 = x3.next_down().next_down(); // -4e
    let x5 = x4.next_down().next_down().next_down().next_down(); // -8e
    let y1 = -2.0f64;
    let y2 = -2.0f64 + 2.0f64.powi(-52) * 36.0;
    let v = vec![
        x1, x2, x3, x3, x4, x4, x4, x4, x5, x5, // -37e
        y1, y1, y1, y1, y1, y1, y1, y1, y1, y2
    ];
    let errors = vec![
        x1 - 2.0, x2 - 2.0, x3 - 2.0, x3 - 2.0, x4 - 2.0,
        x4 - 2.0, x4 - 2.0, x4 - 2.0, x5 - 2.0, x5 - 2.0,
        y1 + 2.0, y1 + 2.0, y1 + 2.0, y1 + 2.0, y1 + 2.0,
        y1 + 2.0, y1 + 2.0, y1 + 2.0, y1 + 2.0, y2 + 2.0
    ];
    let mut sum = 0.0;
    let mut true_sum = 0.0;
    for i in 0..20 {
        sum += v[i];
        true_sum += errors[i];
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
    println!("True: {:.60}", true_sum);
    println!("Got:   {:.60}", sum);
    println!("Rel.Error: {:.10}", (sum - true_sum).abs() / true_sum.abs());
}

Output:
[2.0, 1.9999999999999998, 1.9999999999999996, 1.9999999999999996, 1.9999999999999991,
 1.9999999999999991, 1.9999999999999991, 1.9999999999999991, 1.9999999999999982,
 1.9999999999999982, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
 -1.999999999999992]
True: -0.000000000000000222044604925031308084726333618164062500000000
Got:   0.000000000000007993605777301127091050148010253906250000000000
Rel.Error: 37.0000000000

Try it on Rust Playground!
x.next_down() (nightly feature) finds the closest f64 that is lower than x.
The construction is similar to the absolute error version: accumulate large integer values with increasing amount of error. However, it is necessary to make the sum as small in magnitude as possible to amplify the relative error, so only the first 10 numbers are used to accumulate the error and the other 10 are used to cancel the integer part.
All f64 numbers between 1 and 2 inclusive are uniformly spaced at the units of 2^-52, and rounding errors at larger ranges occur as its multiples, so it is impossible to make the true sum smaller than that in magnitude. It is thus the "unit of error" (e in the comments in code). The true sum is -1e while the calculated sum is +36e, making the relative error exactly 37. (not percent; in percentage it would be 3700%!)

Its interesting the relative error is an integer. What would the max relative error be if the numbers were restricted between 0 and 1 in absolute value?

@Simd Then the true sum can be as low as 5e-324, and a quick try gives 2.247e307 using just 6 numbers. Should be possible to produce 16x ~ 32x of that with 20 numbers.

x1 = 1.0f64 and y5 = -2.0f64 each seem to have errors of zero.  Is there a reason you can't build-in some extra error to these, too?

@DominicvanEssen The error of size e occurs only when the result of an operation is strictly greater than 2. x1 is the first term, so it is always exact. After adding y5, the magnitude cannot be significantly greater than 2, but maybe I didn't try to squeeze e hard enough.

I want to understand how to calculate the true sum. While, i mean, we need the true sum before "sum", but after calculate "2.0f64 - e * 2.0". That's because "2.0f64 - e * 2.0" is not a part of sum calculating. So we need to calculate the the value after "2.0f64 - e * 2.0" first...

@tsh All number literals and the values of x1 through x5 and y1 and y2 are exact. So, in order to calculate the true sum, you can reorder the summands (think of a - b as a + (-b)), collect same-sized literals and cancel them out.
